# Point of symmetry in a probability density function $f_X$ is the mean of $X$.

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

**Conjecture:** Suppose we are given a nice probability distribution function $f(x)$ which is symmetric and  has one single maximum/minima, then show the value of $f(x)$ at the maxima/min is the same as the mean value of $f(x)$ over whole $R$

***The attempt at the proof:***

**The mean of f(x):**

$$ \lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{\int_{-b}^b x f(x) dx}{2b}$$

**The maxima/minima of $f(x)$:**

There is some $x_o$ such that $ f'(x_o) = 0$ and hence $f(x_o)$ is maxima value

**Need to prove:**

$$ f(x_o) = \lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{\int_{-b}^b x f(x) dx}{2b}$$

I'm not very sure how to prove the above equality generally. Any hints/solutions?

Comment: What defines "nice function" here?  A function can have a single global maximum on $\mathbb R$ without that value being the average (mean value).  In fact the only functions for which this can hold would be (almost everywhere) constant.

Comment: Smooth means the function is smooth, continous etc. I thought of this conjecture whilst looking at graphs of functions such as $ y=x^2 $ and the gaussian

Comment: This is not true for $x^2$, a function with a minima whose value at minima is not the same as mean value.

Comment: What would be the characteristic  of functions having such properties?

Comment: Nor is it true of the Gaussian curve.  Averaging the Gaussian over the whole real line will give zero.  As I see it a smooth function with this property is constant, if that counts as having a "single maxima".

Comment: I added some more ideas

Comment: Perhaps you are saying the maximum and the minimum are the same?  Then of course such a function is constant.

Comment: This conjecture was used to prove that this function has same max and mean:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/702561892224467015/762300392859107328/image.png

Comment: It has been pointed out to you by multiple users that your conjecture is false for non-constant $f$. You haven't come up with a single function that serves as an example to your conjecture. Why do you still think it's true? I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: A friend of mine used this property to prove that for a symmetric gaussian , the mean corresponds to the peak value of it

Comment: A symmetric probability density obviously hat it's mean in the point which the distribution is symmetric to. You're question before recent edits asked for something different. Even if you properly fix the question, the conjecture is still wrong for non-symmetric probability distributions.

Comment: I had made some mistakes in the beginning but I think I've caught them all over time.

Comment: Note that the mean of a random variable is not the same as the mean of its probability density function. See my answer for the correct way to calculate the mean of $X$ from a density function $f_X$. (Your factor $\frac{1}{2b}$ is superfluous.) Furthermore, you don't need to talk about maxima / minima: symmetry is enough for this to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be the probability density of a continuous random variable $X$ and assume that $f$ is symmetric with respect to $x_0$ so that
$$
f(x_0+x) = f(x_0-x)
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

The expected value of $X$ is then obtained as
\begin{align}
E[X] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,f(x)\,\mathrm dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{x_0} x\,f(x)\,\mathrm dx + \int_{x_0}^\infty x\,f(x)\,\mathrm dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty (x_0-x)\,f(x_0-x)\,\mathrm dx + \int_0^\infty (x_0+x)\,f(x_0+x)\,\mathrm dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty [(x_0-x)+(x_0+x)] f(x_0+x)\,\mathrm dx \\
&= 2x_0 \int_0^\infty f(x_0+x)\,\mathrm dx \\
&= x_0 \left(\int_0^\infty f(x_0+x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^\infty f(x_0+x)\,\mathrm dx\right) \\
&= x_0 \left(\int_0^\infty f(x_0-x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^\infty f(x_0+x)\,\mathrm dx\right) \\
&= x_0 \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx}_1 = x_0.
\end{align}

Hence, the expected value of $X$ is $E[X]=x_0$.

Note that $E[X]$ is not $f(x_0)$ and neither is it the mean of $f$ as a function, which would be
$$
\lim_{L\to\infty} \frac{1}{2L} \underbrace{\int_{-L}^L f(x)\,\mathrm dx}_{<1} = 0,
$$
since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx=1$ in the case of probability density functions.